# Android.mk for Github Java SDK (win7 32-bit)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, google-project-tango

I am trying to build [tango-examples-java-master/PointCloudJava](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java).

Is there an *Android.mk* for the [tango-examples-java-master/TangoUtils](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/TangoUtils) dependency or should i create one?
In general will Tango SDK developers provide us with a generic makefile that we can tweak according to our multi-platform needs?

Cheers

NY

ps. I know that Tango supports linux only, for now i overcome this by pointing to a GNU-C compiler C:\android-ndk-r10b\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PointCloudJava and TangoUtils are purely java projects with no native components, not sure why you would need a make file here. You just need to specify TangoUtils as a dependency in Project Properties and add it your build path.

Comment: thanks -missed the makefile for NDK samples. Any updates please on the Unity SDK for a Tango-powered tablet? Unity SDK for Peanut can be found, but it 'd be useful to get the tablet implementation as well

Comment: Unity SDK is available on the eap site under downloads section in developer day folder(It points to a folder in google drive).